# Substitute for AnyForwardCollection on Swift 3 (Xcode 8.3)

Tags: swift, swift3

I have an "old" code written in Swift 2.3 (Xcode 8.2.x) that uses the struct `AnyForwardCollection` type.

During the conversion process I figured out that `AnyForwardCollection` was being removed on Swift 3 (Xcode 8.3.x) (confirmed by the [Swift 3.0 API diffs](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/General/watchOS30APIDiffs/Swift/Swift.html) as well).

What can I use as identical alternative to this struct? I can't find anything that fits the same requirements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`AnyCollection`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/anycollection) is the Swift 3 equivalent to Swift 2's `AnyForwardCollection`. It is a type-erased wrapper for any [`Collection`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/collection) conforming type (i.e a type that represents a collection of elements that can be indexed through forwards and be iterated through non-destructively).

For example:

```
// c is an AnyCollection<Int>
var c = AnyCollection([1, 2, 3])

print(c.first!) // 1
print(c[c.index(after: c.startIndex)]) // 2


let set: Set = [4, 5, 6]
c = AnyCollection(set)

for element in c {
    print(element)
}

// 5
// 4
// 6
```

It's worth noting that `AnyCollection`'s collection initialisers ([for example](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/anycollection/2853650-init)) impose many constraints on the collection being passed. These are requirements that are *expected* of types conforming to `Collection` to satisfy – but currently aren't able to be enforced by `Collection` itself due to current inability [to have `where` clauses on associated types](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0142-associated-types-constraints.md) (but this will change in Swift 4).